# FPDF check height of multicell

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to generate a pdf showing product details, obviously this will have variable text length's causing cells to be different heights.

in this case I'm checking how many fragrances the product contains and then showing the name and description for each one, while keeping a track of how many lines this should be taking up.

```
for ($i = 0;$i <= $countfrag; $i++) {
    $pdf->SetXY(102, $next);
    $fragname = $ranges->getFragName($fragcount[$i]);
    $fragdesc = $ranges->getFragDesc($fragcount[$i]);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->MultiCell(88,4, $fragname, 0, L);
    $next = $next + 4;
    $pdf->SetFont('Gill','',11);
    $pdf->SetXY(102, $next);
    $pdf->MultiCell(98,4, $fragdesc, 0, L); 
    $len = $pdf->GetStringWidth($fragdesc);
    $remain = ceil($len / 98) + 1;
    $extra = $remain * 4;
    $next = $next + $extra;
    }
```

as you can see, i'm getting the width of the string with $pdf->GetStringWidth and then dividing that by the width of the multicell (98) then adding 1 to get adding 1 to get an extra line space before the next one prints.

while this is working for the most part it does have problems on a few of the pdfs i'm creating.

I have one where len is being calculated at 373.2784 and it is only giving me a height of 4 lines where as it needs 5 lines of space to be consistent..

Answer (score 0):

FPDF does not support good Multicells!
FPDF has stopped the support, I think some years ago. Use TCPDF it has alsmost the same functions/calls (>95%). Its is full advanced and has a super documentation. TCPDF supports transactions, Multicell and UTF-8.

Comment: still seems to be documented on their website with no sort of deprecation notices. and it's less the functionality of multicells thats the problem than possibly the math i'm using. Unfortunately I don't have time to switch platform on this project.